# Not saving selected spinner value using php and android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-spinner

In my project i am using one spinner item with 3 edittexts fields..here i am sending those values via url to the php file which in turn that php file will store those values to the database...if i use only three edittext fields in my program, it is storing to the database..Now what my problem is, the selected spinner value is not saving in to the database.previously only three edittext values were saving..after spinner is used nothing is saving to the database..
here i want to send three edit text values and selected spinner item as a paramater to the php file..
please help me to save the selected spinner item to the database..

here is my files..

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.server;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spin;
    private EditText editTextFname;
    private EditText editTextLname;
    private EditText editTextMobile;
    //private EditText editTextPin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        editTextFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFname);
        editTextLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLname);
        editTextMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMobile);
        //editTextPin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPin);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinner = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(spinner);

    }

    public void insert(View view){

        String salutation = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();//spinner item..not saving..
        String fname = editTextFname.getText().toString();
        String lname = editTextLname.getText().toString();
        String mobile = editTextMobile.getText().toString();


        insertToDatabase(salutation,fname,lname,mobile);


        /*Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://oursite/insert-db.php"); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String salutation, String fname, String lname,String mobile){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "deprecation" })
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String paramSalutation = params[0];
                String paramFname = params[1];
                String paramLname = params[2];
                String paramMobile = params[3];

                //InputStream is = null;

                String salutation = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String fname = editTextFname.getText().toString();
                String lname = editTextLname.getText().toString();
                String mobile = editTextMobile.getText().toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salutation", salutation));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://oursite/insert-db.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    //is = entity.getContent();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(salutation,fname,lname,mobile);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**insert-db.php**

```
<?php

    define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
    define('USER','u449667615_user');
    define('PASS','1234');
    define('DB','u449667615_db');

    $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

  $salutation = $_POST['salutation'];   
  $fname = $_POST['fname'];
  $lname = $_POST['lname'];
  $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];


   $sql = "insert into person (salutation,fname,lname,mobile) values ('$salutation','$fname','$lname','$mobile')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Please check databse field name name and tabel schema.

Comment: Table names are correct...but spinner value is not saving..

Comment: please check all values get in php file useing echo.

Comment: nothing is getting printed when i did echo..

Comment: how to call insert() method?

Comment: @Drew..yes ..now it is getting saved in database..i dont know what was the issue..previously it was not saving anything..now the above code works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Check `spin.getSelectedItem().toString()` return value. 
Also try to `echo` values in php moving the `echo $_POST['salutation'];` to last position, because if it fails it will crash the following echos.